# struts2 problem in action

Tags: struts2, action

I've started an application using struts 2.0.14 and web server is apache tomcat 6.0. 
I am getting an error, please help me to solve this.

Application name: **strutsTest**

Welcome page: **EmpDetails.jsp** in a package named ‘**validTest**’ having action like:

```
<s:form action="takeAction" method="post>
```

Action class: Employee.java and also I wrote Employee-validation.xml.

Now when I run my application it opens with following url: `http://localhost:8080/strutsTest/validTest/empDetails.jsp`

There is only textbox in empDetails.jsp named email and I am validating this textbox using employee-validation.xml
To test this I entered an invalid email and got an error message on the top of same welcome page (empDetails.jsp). But this url changed to: 
`http://localhost:8080/strutsTest/validTest/takeAction.action`

Not an issue. Now, I entered valid email and submit but got an error message instead of next page i.e thanks.jsp and url has changed to -

`http://localhost:8080/strutsTest/takeAction.action`

Error is:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /strutsTest/thanks.jsp

type Status report

message  /strutsTest/thanks.jsp

description The requested resource (/simpleStruts2.0.14/thanks.jsp) is not available.
```

Answer (score 2):

From your description, the validation part is excluded for your problem. In your struts.xml file, you may have configure the result as:

```
<action name="takeAction" ...>           
    <result>/simpleStruts2.0.14/thanks.jsp</result>
</action>
```

The result page: /simpleStruts2.0.14/thanks.jsp is not available(so HTTP 404 response), you may changed to something like this:

```
<result>/validTest/thanks.jsp</result>
```